# Logical NOT of an implication

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was looking through my notes but I was unable to find the answer to this, which I need to start am assignment question.

What would the following be, in terms on moving the negation inside the brackets and keeping the implication:

$\neg (p  \rightarrow q)$

Comment: The negation of $\neg (p  \rightarrow q)$ is $\neg\neg (p  \rightarrow q)$, more commonly written as $p  \rightarrow q$ (though you have now changed the question).

Comment: In $p \rightarrow q$, three of the four possibilities are true.  In $\neg (p  \rightarrow q)$ only one of the four possibilities is true.  So it is not an implication in any simple way.  Similarly, when you negate $p$ AND $q$, the result is not an AND statement.  It is an OR statement.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Recall that $p\rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\lnot p\lor q$. From here:

$$\lnot(p\rightarrow q)\iff\lnot(\lnot p\lor q)\iff \lnot\lnot p\land\lnot q\iff p\land\lnot q$$

One can consider the truth table:

$$\begin{array}{ c | c || c | c |}
  p & q & p\rightarrow q & \lnot(p\rightarrow q) \\ \hline
  \text T & \text T & \text T & \text F\\
  \text T & \text F & \text F & \text T \\
  \text F & \text T & \text T & \text F \\
  \text F & \text F & \text T & \text F 
\end{array}$$

And from this we can see that $\lnot(p\rightarrow q)\iff p\land\lnot q$.

---

It is also visible that $\rightarrow$ has a True value three out of four times. So $\lnot(p\rightarrow q)$ cannot be written as $\lnot p\rightarrow q$, or as a similar proposition using only a single $\rightarrow$.

This is because to say that $p$ does not imply $q$ says nothing about $p$ implying $\lnot q$, or about $\lnot p$ implying $q$.

Comment: I've been told that $p \rightarrow q$ is equally true and false, if $p$ is false..

Comment: @Max: Okay...???

Answer (score 5):

Since $p\to q\equiv \lnot p\vee q$, we can apply DeMorgan's laws to see that

$\lnot(p\to q)\equiv \lnot(\lnot p\vee q)\equiv p \wedge \lnot q$. You can write out a truth table of the left hand side of the formula and the right hand side to further affirm the statement.

Answer (score 2):

You (or other readers of this question) might be interested in the analysis [here](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/basic-logic-connectives-implies/), and the related posts.

Comment: Are you sure this shouldn't really be a comment?

Comment: @AsafKaragila: you are right, but I was in a hurry, and I get some editing tools and a preview to check that the link is working when I do an answer. Sorry if this is against protocol.

Comment: You can use `[text](URL)` for a link the comments, after a while it becomes easier to use that in answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent form of this statement with negations inside brackets and keeping the implication can be constructed if we use logical relationship [contraposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition#Formal_definition) so we may write following:

$\lnot(p\Rightarrow q) \Leftrightarrow \lnot(\lnot q \Rightarrow \lnot p)$

but you cannot write any form that satisfies your conditions without negation in front of the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question as basically asking "can we write a formula F logically equivalent to ¬(p→q) where F 1. is a conditional and 2. has a negation somewhere inside the conditional?"  The answer is yes.  I'll try to explain how I saw this first before providing an actual formula which does this.

First, since this question asks about the primary connective of a logical statement, let's rewrite all formulas in prefix notation.  In other words, let's rewrite all formulas such that all logical operations precede their arguments (e. g. (p→q) becomes →pq).  The first symbol for a formula in prefix notation indicates the type of statement.  So, our problem becomes to find a formula with "→" as its first symbol with a negation symbol somewhere else in the formula.

Now implication and negation together form a set of adequate connectives for (two-valued) propositional logic.  In other words, all formulas in (two-valued) propositional logic come as equivalent, in prefix notation, to a formula which has a conditional symbol or a negation symbol as its first symbol.  Now The Sheffer Stroke "D", or Alternative Denial (NAND), by itself consists of an adequate connective; where D can get defined by the following table with 0 symbolizing falsity and 1 symbolizing truth:

```
D  0  1
0  1  1
1  1  0
```

The following logical equivalences (==) hold: 1. Dxx == ¬x, 2. Dxy == →x¬y.  Now, since all formulas come as equivalent to a conditional or a negation, and every conditional or negation comes as equivalent to a Sheffer Stroke formula, and every Sheffer Stroke formula comes as equivalent to a conditional with a negation somewhere inside that conditional by 2., it follows that all formulas in classical propositional logic come as equivalent to such a conditional.  One could make a similar argument using Peirce's arrow, or joint denial (NOR).

So, how might "¬(p→q)" or equivalently "¬→pq" look as a conditional?  Well, substitute →pq for x in 1. above and we have ¬→pq comes as logically equivalent to D→pq→pq.  Next, substituting →pq for both x and for y in 2. above we have D→pq→pq as logically equivalent to →→pq¬→pq.  In infix notation that goes ((p→q)→(¬(p→q))).