# What are we doing when we are proofing a theorem "if A, then B"?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

What are we doing when we are proofing a theorem "if A, then B"?Are we proving that "if A, then B" is true? We know "if A, then B" is true when A is true and B is true. So are we proving that B is try when A is true ? But we also know "if A, then B" is true when A is false and B is true ,or A is false and B is false. So can we prove "if A, then B" by proving B is false when A is false ? Or B is true when A is false ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71809/logical-not-of-an-implication this thread has a good explanation imo

Answer (score 0):

We are show that the statement

$$A \to B$$

is a tautology.

In other words, if $A$ is true, than there is no such a case where $B$ is false (provided $A$ is true)

Comment: But What does it mean when we say "if A then B" is true ?

Comment: Say, for example, $A:$ This is a sunny day, and $B:$ Today is going to be a good day, and you have somehow proved that $A\to B$. Then if you wake up a morning  and see that that day is a sunny day, then you are %$100$ sure that that day is going to be a good day.

Comment: In other words, provided that the statement $A$ is true, then the statement $B$ is also true.

Comment: So can I say proving "if A, then B" is to show that "if A, then B" is true ?

Comment: @user579146 Yes that is correct. Actually, that is what a tautology means. It means the statement $(A \to B)$ is always true regardless of the values of $A$.

Comment: But can I prove "if A then B" is true by saying B is false (or true) when A is false? Because "if A then B" is true when A is false and B is false( or true)

Comment: @user579146 No, because when the statement $A\to B$ is true, the fact that $A$ is false does not mean that $B$ is false also (You might want to check if and only if statements, denoted $\iff$) . In other words, when $A$ is false, $B$ can be true or false, provided that the statement $A\to B $ is true.

Comment: @user579146 Please let me know if anything is not clear.