# How many true statements are there in following statements?

Tags: logic

We know that the statement "If  today it rains, I will stay home" is false. what is the  true statement among these four?

1. If today it doesn't rain, I wont stay home.
2. If today I don't stay home, It won't rain.
3. Today it rained and I didn't stay home.
4. Today I stayed home and it didn't rain.

I tried
$$
\begin{align}
A &= \text{Today it rains},\\
B &= \text{I will stay home},
\end{align}
$$
Because $ A \rightarrow B$ false, then $A$ true and $ B $ false.

1. $ \neg A  $ is false, therefore 1. is true.
2. $ \neg B  $ is true and $ \neg A  $ is false, then 2. is false.
3. Both $ A $ and $ \neg B  $ are true, then 3. is true.
4. $ \neg B $ is true, then 4 is false.

My answer there are two statements: 1 and 3.

Comment: I assume that "wrong" means FALSE. Thus, we have that "if R, then H" is FALSE, i.e. its negation will be TRUE. The negation of "if R, then H" will be : "R and not H".

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify why option 1. cannot be considered true.

Comment: Negation of option 1. Is FALSE, then 1. Is true. I think so.

Answer (score 1):

I think the statements can be simplified by removing the temporal component, since I suppose the exercise is not about temporal implications:

1. If it does not rain, I do not stay home.
2. If I do not stay home, it does not rain.
3. It does rain, but I do not stay home.
4. I do stay home, but it does not rain.

Now, setting
$$
\begin{align}
A &= \text{it does rain},\\
B &= \text{I do stay home},
\end{align}
$$
we can express the four statements as:

1. $\neg A \rightarrow \neg B \quad \equiv \quad A \lor \neg B$.
2. $\neg B \rightarrow \neg A \quad \equiv \quad B \lor \neg A$.
3. $A \land \neg B $.
4. $B \land \neg A$.

The assumption is that "If it does rain, I do stay home" is FALSE, hence that $A \rightarrow B$ is FALSE. Therefore $\neg (A \rightarrow B)$ is TRUE or, [equivalently](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/71810/607587), $A \land \neg B$.

We conclude that:

1. Is TRUE, since $(A \land \neg B) \rightarrow (A \lor \neg B)$;
2. Is FALSE, since $(A \land \neg B) \land (B \lor \neg A) \rightarrow \bot $;
3. Is TRUE, since $(A \land \neg B) \equiv(A \land \neg B) $;
4. Is FALSE, since $(A \land \neg B) \land (B \land \neg A) \rightarrow \bot$.

Comment: Because $A→B$ false, then A true and B false. Therefore ¬A is false. Thus Negation of option 1. Is FALSE, then 1. Is true. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Now I agree with you. Thanks, I edited my answer.

Comment: I dont know why my question is downvoted and closed (1).

Comment: Nor do I know why it is downvoted, but to me it seems not closed.